# Outputing lines of filenames with highest number

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of files with a pattern of `.*_[0-9]*\.txt` in a file like this:

```
todo_1.txt
todo_3.txt
todo_91.txt
done_44.txt
done_12000203.txt
```

The suffix of the filename always ends with `_[0-9]*.txt`, while the prefix can be `[a-zA-Z0-9.]*`. I would like to output only the files with the largest number:

```
todo_91.txt
done_12000203.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ perl -lne '($prefix,$num) = m/^(.*)_(\d+).*$/;
             if ($num > $n{$prefix}) { $f{$prefix} = $_; $n{$prefix} = $num };
             END { foreach (sort keys %f) { print $f{$_} } }' input.txt 
done_12000203.txt
shopping.list_292.txt
todo_91.txt
```

This quick and dirty perl hack splits extracts the filename prefixes and numbers from each input line and uses them to build two hash arrays - `%n` to hold the highest number for each filename prefix, and `%f` to hold the associated filename.  Both hashes use the same key (the prefix).

It captures everything before the `_` as the "prefix", and all digits after the `_` (up to either the end of the line or the first non-digit character) as the number.

Lines that do not match the `^(.*)_(\d+).*$` regex pattern are completely ignored.  If you want, you can print a warning message if that happens (left as an exercise for the reader).

Once it's read the input, it iterates over the keys of one of the `%f` hash and prints the filename.

---

and here's a slightly fancier version of the same thing as a standalone perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my (%f,%n);

while(<>) {
  s/#.*//;          # strip comments (#)
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g;   # strip leading and trailing spaces
  next if (m/^$/);  # ignore blank lines
  chomp;   # strip newline from end of line.

  my ($prefix,$num) = m/^(.*)_(\d+).*$/;

  if ($num > $n{$prefix}) {
    $f{$prefix} = $_;
    $n{$prefix} = $num;
  };
}

foreach (sort keys %f) {
  print $f{$_}, "\n";
}
```

Save it as, e.g., `find-largest.pl` and make it executable with `chmod +x find-largest.pl` and run it like so:

```
$ ./find-largest.pl input.txt 
done_12000203.txt
shopping.list_292.txt
todo_91.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works fine with the example I gave, but I didn't detailed the format of the suffix, so for filenames like `shopping.list_93.txt` and `shopping.list_292.txt` it won't work. Could you change this?

Comment: @Kazh updated the one-liner to use a regex instead of split.  try it now.

Comment: I saw your edit, the one-liner works now, and the standalone script works too.